# How can we customize scroll view in iphone?

Tags: uiscrollview, core-plot, xcode4.5, iphone-5

Here I am using a two pie chart and it having a pagination.My problems is in landscape mode  the pie chart have move every where in iphone screen. Please be give any idea to scroll in landscape mode

```
          [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
          [myScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 480, 290-40)];
          [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480*2, 400.00)];
          [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(480*currentPageTop, 0.00)];
          [pageControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 30.00, 480, 20.00)];
          [pageControl setCurrentPage:currentPageTop]
```

Comment: For that you have to give us an idea with some code :)